# Android のナビゲーションバーと解像度の関係について

Tags: android

現在作成中のアプリにて、解像度 1280 * 720 (16:9) で画面を設計しました。
解像度2560 * 1440 のアンドロイド端末で問題なく見ることができていました。
本日、ナビゲーションバーが出ていないことに気づいて、ナビゲーションバーを出すように設定したところ、表示がおかしくなりました。（縮小された）
※ Unityのcanvasの設定で解像度設定をしているため、全体が入るように縮小されたと思われます。

ここで質問なのですが、
1. 端末スペックなどで言われている解像度は、ナビゲーションバーを含んだ解像度であって、実際のアプリで使える範囲の解像度は、それより小さくなるということでしょうか？
2.ナビゲーションバーを表示するアプリ（表示されているアプリが多いと思いますが）は、ナビゲーションバーの高さを考慮して作成されているのでしょうか？
3. ナビゲーションバーの高さの取得仕方を調べたところ、Unityでは取得できないようなのですが、対処法はありますでしょうか？

開発終盤で解像度が変わる自体になりそうで、大変困ってます。
よろしくお願いいたします。